# How to modify xml file in c#

Tags: c#, xml, uwp

I want to use XML as user data. I want to add a feature so users can edit their profile in my app. But, I'm having an issue with XML editing.

```
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.Storage;

private async void btn_save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
     StorageFile file = await  storageFolder.GetFileAsync("file.xml");
     string fileContent = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.LoadXml(fileContent);
     XmlNodeList tags = doc.GetElementsByTagName("person");

     if (tags.Count > 0)
     {
          int index;
          for (int i = 0; i < tags.Count; i++)
          {
               if(tags.ElementAt(i).Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").InnerText == personId && tags.ElementAt(i).Attributes.GetNamedItem("id") != null)
               {
                   index = i;
                   break;
               }
          }
          XmlAttribute attr_name = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
          attr_name.Value = txtBox_name.Text;
          tags.ElementAt(index).Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr_name);

          await doc.SaveToFileAsync(file);
     }
}
```

By using this method, I've got this exception when re-read a saved xml file:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE558

That's because my xml file gone empty after saving it.  So, how to modify my xml file?

**UPDATE:**

```
await doc.SaveToFileAsync(file);
```

I suspect this is a major problem. I have no idea how to save modified xml.
Anyway, XML is not empty even before I start to modify it. It already has some tags there.

Please check the copy of my project here:
https://github.com/wonyh-b/Modify-XML

Comment: It doesn't look sound to me, saving the file inside the loop - try saving it only once after finishing your loop.

Comment: @Filburt it would happen only once, because every single person id is unique. I'm using it for searching a target tag.

Comment: Then there should be no need for a loop. In any case I'd move it outside the loop (inside the `if`) and inspect the returned ActionResult - I'm pretty sure it will be able to tell you what's going wrong. I don't have time right no to look closer at what you are doing here but i suspect there's something about the change to the Xml doc.

Comment: @Filburt okay, I've moved it. but it didn't resolve anything.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem occurs at `doc.LoadXml(fileContent); `, i.e. the file is empty before you even start modifying it. That's why you should 1.) post a call stack for the error you get and 2.) reduce your code to a [mre] While trying to remove code that does not affect the result, you'd probably find that only 5 lines are needed and the whole loop is not relevant.

Comment: So, how to proceed? Create a copy of your project for Stack Overflow, put it into a local Git repo, start removing code and commit as long as the result does not change (i.e. the problem is still there). When the problem is gone, undo/revert the last change and try to remove other code instead.

Comment: You are first using the .InnerText of `tags.ElementAt(i).Attributes.GetNamedItem("id")` and after that you check whether that nameditem isn't null - you should switch that around! Personally I would capture that nameditem in a local variable (and then testing that) instead of finding it twice.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  .NET Core 3.x?  .NET 5?  If .NET Core 3.x then [Unable to use XmlWriter asynchronously #42509](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42509) might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That's because my xml file gone empty after saving it. So, how to modify my xml file?

During the testing, the problem looks occur in `doc.SaveToFileAsync(file)` line, please feel free report it with windows feed back hub, please let me know if you have reported, And currently, we have a workaround that write string to replace  [`SaveToFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.xml.dom.xmldocument.savetofileasync?view=winrt-19041) method.

```
if (tags.Count > 0)
{
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tags.Count; i++)
    {
        if (tags.ElementAt(i).Attributes.GetNamedItem("id").InnerText == "12345678901234"/*this is a unique id, based on xml*/ && tags.ElementAt(i).Attributes.GetNamedItem("id") != null)
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    XmlAttribute attr_name = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
    attr_name.Value = txtBox_name.Text;
    tags.ElementAt(index).Attributes.SetNamedItem(attr_name);
     // get xml string
    var data = doc.GetXml();
     /* await doc.SaveToFileAsync(file); */
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, data);

}
```

Comment: Just a guess here, but if querent is running on on .NET Core 3.x then this is possibly related to [Unable to use XmlWriter asynchronously #42509](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42509).

Comment: Yep, But `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom` is uwp specific, and it's not apply to .NET Core 3.x.